# Advice For Optimizing My Fractal Encoding Neural Net

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network, fractals

This my first post on stackoverflow so please go lightly!

I've been working on a small side project that will take a greyscale image, and produce a fractal which (hopefully) approximates that image by a binary square matrix (you can find a general overview of the process I am talking about [here](http://www.chem.unt.edu/~mauldin/papers/no67.pdf)!). I have the ability to make many (40k+) image matrix pairs, but for now I have only generated 9k.

Right now I am thinking of the problem like this: I put in an image of size = (100, 100, 1) with values in the range [0, 1], and I get out an image of size = (9, 9, 1) with values in the set {0, 1}. At some point, I will have to force the output of the model to be a binary matrix, no matter what the model eventually gives me.

Here's an example image matrix pair:

[Here's the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vevNv.png), original fractal to the left of the resized image for training

[Here's the Matrix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QoXzK.png), a 9x9 binary matrix, yellow is where there are ones and purple are zeros

I've been able to compile and 'fit' the following model in keras:

```
n = 6500 #the amount of training samples, with 9000-n = 2500 samples for testing

training_images = np.array([x.reshape(100, 100, 1) for x in all_files[:n,0]])
training_mats =  np.array([x.reshape(9, 9, 1) for x in all_files[:n, 1]])

testing_images = np.array([x.reshape(100, 100, 1) for x in all_files[n:,0]])
testing_mats =  np.array([x.reshape(9, 9, 1) for x in all_files[n:, 1]])

nepochs = 20
#create model

model = keras.Sequential()

#conv2d_13
model.add(keras.layers.Conv2D(5, kernel_size=11, activation=tf.nn.relu, input_shape=(100,100, 1)))

#conv2d_14
model.add(keras.layers.Conv2D(4, (5, 5), activation='relu', padding='same'))

#max_pooling2d_5
model.add(keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(5, 5), strides=None, padding='valid'))

#conv2d_15
model.add(keras.layers.Conv2D(1, (5, 5), activation='relu',padding='same'))

#max_pooling2d_6
model.add(keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=None, padding='valid'))

#conv2d_16
model.add(keras.layers.Conv2D(1, (3, 3), activation='relu',padding='same'))

#conv2d_18
model.add(keras.layers.Conv2D(1, (3, 3), activation='relu',padding='same'))

model.compile(optimizer='adamax', loss='mse', metrics=[ 'mae'])
model.summary()
model.fit(training_images, training_mats,validation_data=(testing_images, testing_mats), epochs=nepochs)
model.save("\models\initial_base9_inverse_model.h5")
```

On the last of 20 epochs, I get the following results:

loss: 0.4416 
mean_absolute_error: 0.3996 
val_loss: 0.4046 
val_mean_absolute_error: 0.4160

Here are my main questions:

1. How can I, in a broad sense, increase the error and loss of my model?
2. The output of the model right now is not strictly a binary matrix, is there anyway to 'force' the output of the model to produce a binary matrix?
3. What optimizer should I be using for this type of problem?
4. What types of loss and metrics would be more appropriate?